# how to pass a list of objects of View in a bundle

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle, parcelable, serializable

i want to save the contents of an ArrayList of Views "ArrayList". i overriden the method "onSaveInstanceState" as shown below in the code, but at run time i receive the below posted logcat errors .
please let em know how to set a list of View objects in a bundle

**code**:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.w(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");

    if (this.mListViews != null && this.mListViews.size() > 0) {
        outState.putSerializable(KEY_LIST_OF_VIEWS, this.mListViews);
   }
  }
```

**logcat**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value android.widget.ImageView{8787bd0 V.ED..... ........ 20,20-1580,2247}
                          at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1419)
                          at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:760)
                          at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1366)
                          at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:687)
                          at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1330)
                          at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079)
                          at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:712)
                          at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3753)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:4704)
                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Can you please post the pojo class of arraylist?

Comment: Do not put Views to Bundle ... put data only

Comment: @Selvin it is a list of Views..each item is a View

Comment: And? you made 'em based on some data ... send the data not views  ... also Do you know that **`onSaveInstanceState` is not for saving persistant data** ?

Comment: Selvin is also right you can put only the primitive data type in bundle not the views

Comment: @Selvin .is it ok to pass a list of Bitmaps?

Answer (score 0):

you should not save the view in savedInstanceState. you should only save the value of the listview. it view will be created automatically

Comment: I am not saving Views...i want to save a list of Views...each item in the list is a View

Comment: list of views means, view object right.? whatever, you should not do it. Views are heavy weight object. and when activity orientation changes, all views will be destroyed and recreated automatically.

Comment: fine..is it ok to pass a list of Bitmaps?

Comment: yes. but you will face OutOfMemory error. because, each bitmap may have large in size.